# Latex Longtable - Caption starts at margin

Tags: captions, longtable

I am having a problem using longtable `\caption`. The captions are not set to `\textlength` and run into the margins. I would like the multi-line captions to be restricted to `\textlength` and centred under the table itself.

[image: screenshot 1]

[image: screenshot 2]

I have tried:

```
\usepackage{caption} \captionsetup[table]{singlelinecheck=false}
\usepackage{caption} \captionsetup[longtable]{singlelinecheck=false}

\LTcapwidth=\textwidth
```

All to no avail.

A sample table is:

```
\LTcapwidth=\textwidth
\begin{longtable}[c]{l c c c c c c}
 & $p < 0.05$ & $p < 0.01$ & $p < 0.001$ & $p < 10^{-6}$ & $p < 10^{-7}$ & $p <                 p_{\text{genome}}$\\
SNP p-value & 80 & 80 & 80 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
SNP p-value Inverse & 80 & 80 & 80 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
Tree Min p-value & 80 & 80 & 80 & 4 & 1 & 0\\
Tree Min p-value Inverse & 80 & 80 & 80 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\label{tab:nullpop}
\caption{A summary of the minimum p-value results for the trees built with     \possessivecite{RefWorks:116} null population data. The value used for $p <     p_{\text{genome}}$ is the value derived from the 1000 Genomes Data of $p < 10^{-8.86}$.}
\end{longtable}
```

Comment: please make your example a complete document that shows the effect. what is `\centerize` ? it is not a command I recognise.

Comment: Put `\label` _inside_ the caption not before it.

Comment: great, thank you! If you want to make it an answer I will mark it.

Comment: I have removed \centerize it was used in a table that I copied the structure from.

Comment: @ThaddeusAid By complete, we mean from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`. That we can copy and compile to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\label` should never be before `\caption` and in particular a `\caption` in a `longtable` has to be the complete row, so it is best to put `\label` in the caption argument.